# Is there a python function to inject a text into the address bar of any web browser?

Tags: python, web, browser

Is it possible to use python to inject or enter any text into the address bar of any web browser?
If possible then, please can I have a code or function with explanations on how either works?
Thanks so much in advance for the help.

Comment: This is quite broad. Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Import webbrowser  , from selenium import webdriver import pyautogui ... Use any of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the selenium module, assuming you are using chrome your code should look something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
chromeBinary = '/home/seldisul/Downloads/chromedriver'#enter the directory to your chrome binary here
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chrome'#enter the directory to your chrome application here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeBinary, chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63606315/is-there-a-python-function-to-inject-a-text-into-the-address-bar-of-any-web-brow')#enter your url here
```

you can get the chrome binary for your version of chrome here:https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

and if you want to find the version of chrome you are using, here's a guide:

1. Click on the Menu icon in the upper right corner of the screen.
2. Click on Help, and then About Google Chrome.
3. Your Chrome browser version number can be found here.

Comment: No problem, this was my first answer on stack overflow so it's great to hear it helped someone.